# Query to retrieve groups where all related values are null

Tags: sql

I have the following:

```
| Group_ID | Value |
|----------|-------|
|      146 |  A    |
|      146 |  B    |
|      239 |  NULL |
|      239 |  F    |
|      826 |  NULL |
|      826 |  NULL |
```

I need to retrieve only the IDs that have all related values null. 
In this example, the output would be `826`.

I know that it seems to be a simple query, but I'm struggling with this for a long time.

Comment: You're spoiled for choice :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select group_id 
from t
group by group_id having sum(case when value is null then 1 end)=count(*)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
select t1.group_id
from foo t1
group by t1.group_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) 
                   from foo t2 
                   where t2.group_id = t1.group_id
                     and t2.value is null);
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7d228/1

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Group_ID
FROM    Your_Table a
WHERE   Value IS NULL
   AND  NOT EXISTS (
                     SELECT   NULL
                     FROM     Your_Table b
                     WHERE    Value IS NOT NULL
                         AND  b.Group_ID = a.Group_ID
                   )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select distinct Group_id 
from test 
where value is null 
   and Group_id not in (select Group_id from test where value is not null)
```